# C++ Microsoft Visual Studio error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I go to **file** > **new** > **project**, there are 3 bars. This is the left one:

[image]

However, in the several C++ Visual Studio tutorials I've compared, the sidebar looked like this:

[image]

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like its time to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you read your first image "_Not finding what you are looking for?_ **Open Visual Studio Installer**" If you clicked <-- that link ... ***You should include that information in your question!*** If you didn't try what is quite clearly recommended, then _you're going to face an uphill battle until you learn to be a little self-sufficient_.

Comment: That button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Click back on the VS installer (the executable that you use to install VS). Then from there, install what you are missing. For C++, it is the one that I boxed with a red rectangle Make sure that it is check. Otherwise, check it and install it. Sorry if my picture is in french.
[image]